# Get row from table based on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get row from based on parameter value. Either it could be value 'ABC' or NULL. Below is the source table and expected result, which I'm trying to achieve.

**SourceTable**

```
    column1    column2  
--------------------------
    value1     NULL  
    value2     ABC
```

Tried with query, but it is getting two rows which are with value1 and value2.

```
Declare @Param1 varchar(20) = 'ABC'

Select * 
from SourceTable 
where column2 = @Param1 Or column2 is NULL
```

If value is 'ABC' then **Result** -

```
column1    column2  
--------------------------
value2     ABC
```

If value is NULL then **Result** -

```
column1    column2  
--------------------------
value1     NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like: Only problem you might encounter with this is if your column2 has blanks.

```
SELECT * 
FROM SourceTable 
WHERE ISNULL(column2, '') = ISNULL(@Param1, '')
```

Comment: Maybe nothing to worry about here, but you might read about `ISNULL()` and "sargable" ...

Comment: I would say that SARGability is always something to worry about. This query might be ok for performance but somebody else will come along and copy it and not understand why the other query is so horribly slow. It is easy enough to fix once you know there is a problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this would work for you?

```
select * 
from SourceTable 
where column2 = @Param1 or (@Param1 is null and column2 is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want `union all` and a check for existence:

```
Select *
from SourceTable
where column2 = @Param1
union all
Select *
from SourceTable
where column2 is null and not exists (select 1 from sourcetable st2 where st2.column2 = @Param1);
```

An alternative uses order by -- if you want only one row:

```
select top 1 st.*
from sourcetable st
where column2 = @param1 or column2 is null
order by (case when column2 is not null then 1 else 2 end);
```